# How to use OpenGL with SKCanvasView on Windows?

Tags: maui, skiasharp

I have a control inheriting from `SKCanvasView`, but the performance is not that great. From previous projects I know that I can create a `GRContext` and pass it while creating an `SKSurface`. However `SKCanvasView` seems to create it's surface internally, so I have no way to pass it myself. Can I use OpenGL with `SKCanvasView` (on Windows) and if so, how?

Comment: [OPINION] With Xamarin I relied on OpenGL cross-platform. But now the graphics ecosystem seems to be splintering at the hardware level (Metal; Tizen). Notably, .Net's [OpenGLVIew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.openglview?view=net-maui-7.0) is marked OBSOLETE! If someone integrates SKCanvasView with [Silk.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET), that might be the starting point for a good path forward.